# Puppeteer looping through URLs UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ProtocolError: Protocol error (Target.createTarget): Target closed

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

this is my first node project so go easy, I have this scraper that uses puppeteer. the first iteration of it worked well, but i wanted to modularize it further. I've gotten it to what feels like an ok place but now I'm running it and it crashes after about 4 urls are scraped (out of about 100)

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ProtocolError: Protocol error (Target.createTarget): Target closed.
```

With my log statements, it looks like something is happening with my awaits, but i can't seem to find the issue. It's not looping in order or waiting for the first loop iteration to finish before starting the next one, and its trying to crawl both sites at once. I've seen some info on that specific error out there, but nothing was related to my situation so I'm assuming it's me.

also, the old version had one fewer loop inside the promise, so this feels like the culprit potentially

```js
const scraperObject = {
    async scraper(browser, queryString, scraperProps){
        let scrapedData = [];
        let queryResults = [];
        let page = await browser.newPage();

        for (const prop of scraperProps) {
            let result = Object.assign({}, prop);
            await page.goto(prop.queryUrl+queryString);
            await page.waitForSelector(prop.selector);
            urls = await page.$$eval(prop.selector, links => { 
                links = links.map(el => el.href.split('?')[0]); // remove params
                return [...new Set(links)]; //dedupe (to remove "promoted" listings that may appear twice)
            });
            result.resultUrls = urls;
            queryResults.push(result);
        }   
        
        // Loop through each of those links, open a new page instance and get the relevant data from them
        // This may not be necessary since the search results page potentially could have most of the info needed, and wouldnt really work for a UI

        let resultPagePromise = (res) => new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
            for(const resUrl of res.resultUrls) {
                console.log(resUrl);
                let dataObj = {};
                let newPage = await browser.newPage();
                await newPage.goto(resUrl);
                dataObj['listingUrl'] = resUrl;
                dataObj['title'] = await newPage.$eval(res.titleSelector, text => text.textContent);
                dataObj['condition'] = await newPage.$eval(res.conditionSelector, text => text.textContent);
                
                if(res.site === 'ebay') { 
                    let iframeGetter = await newPage.waitForSelector('iframe#desc_ifr');
                    let frame = await iframeGetter.contentFrame();
                    await frame.waitForSelector(res.descriptionSelector);
                    dataObj['description'] = await frame.$eval(res.descriptionSelector, text => text.textContent.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r|\t)/gm, ""));
                } else {
                    dataObj['description'] = await newPage.$eval(res.descriptionSelector, text => text.textContent.replace(/(\r\n\t|\n|\r|\t)/gm, ""));
                }   

                dataObj['price'] = await newPage.$eval(res.priceSelector, text => text.textContent);
                dataObj['location'] = await newPage.$eval(res.locationSelector, text => text.textContent);         
                dataObj['imageUrl'] = await newPage.$eval(res.imageUrlSelector, img => img.src);
                resolve(dataObj);
                await newPage.close();
            }
        });

        for(const res of queryResults){ 
            console.log(res);
            let currentPageData = await resultPagePromise(res);
            scrapedData.push(currentPageData);
        }
        await page.close();
        console.log(scrapedData);
        return scrapedData;
    } 
}

module.exports = scraperObject;
```

Answer (score 0):

Noob mistake, I needed to resolve the array of "dataObjs" in the promise instead the single object in each loop iteration. so returning an array of dataobjs instead of the single object worked.